# QML signal with a C++ enum type

Tags: qt, enums, qml, signals-slots

I have a class which I am exposing to QML as follows:

```
#ifndef MYTYPE_H
#define MYTYPE_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>


class MyType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(TestEnum)
    Q_PROPERTY(TestEnum foo READ foo WRITE setFoo NOTIFY fooChanged)

public:

    enum class TestEnum
    {
        State1 = 1,
        State2 = 2
    };

    MyType(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent),
        mFoo(TestEnum::State1)
    {
    }

    TestEnum foo() const
    {
        return mFoo;
    }

    void setFoo(TestEnum foo)
    {
        if (foo == mFoo)
            return;

        mFoo = foo;
        emit fooChanged(mFoo);
    }

signals:
    void fooChanged(MyType::TestEnum blah);

private:
    TestEnum mFoo;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType::TestEnum)

#endif // MYTYPE_H
```

Here I have an enumeration type which I would like to expose to QML.

I register the type n my main function call as:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyType>("App", 1, 0, "MyType");
```

Now I have a signal in my qml file which I takes this enumeration parameter:

```
signal submitTextField(MyType::TestEnum state) // Compiler complains here
```

The signal is connected as:

```
QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
//QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
// This is just a class that implements the slot
HandleTextField handleTextField;
// connect our QML signal to our C++ slot
QObject::connect(topLevel, SIGNAL(submitTextField(MyType::TestEnum)),
                     &handleTextField, SLOT(handleSubmitTextField(MyType::TestEnum)));
```

The class that implements the slot is defined as:

```
class HandleTextField : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HandleTextField(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void handleSubmitTextField(MyType::TestEnum in);
    void handleFooChanged(MyType::TestEnum in);
public:
    MyType myType;

};
```

The syntax `MyType::TestEnum` is not valid. I am tempted to convert everything to `ints` and do away with the enumeration but wondering if there is a way to use this enumeration type in a QML signal. I can do `MyType.State1 and MyType.State2` but unable to refer to the enumeration type.

Comment: What do you mean by unable to refer to the enumeration type ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: @perencia Edited some code. Just trying to do a signal slot connection between C++ and Qt where the signal defined in QML takes a enumeration type as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it does not seem like this can be done with enums i.e. you have to use `ints`. I made the following change and it works:

```
class MyType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(TestEnum)
    Q_PROPERTY(TestEnum foo READ foo WRITE setFoo NOTIFY fooChanged)

public:

    enum TestEnum
    {
        State1 = 1,
        State2 = 2
    };

    MyType(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QObject(parent),
        mFoo(TestEnum::State1)
    {
    }

    TestEnum & foo()
    {
        return mFoo;
    }

    void setFoo(TestEnum foo)
    {
        if (foo == mFoo)
            return;

        mFoo = foo;
        emit fooChanged(static_cast<int>(mFoo));
    }

signals:
    void fooChanged(int blah);

private:
    TestEnum mFoo;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType::TestEnum)
```

The slots need to be changed as well:

```
class HandleTextField : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HandleTextField(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void handleSubmitTextField(int in);
    void handleFooChanged(int in);
public:
    MyType myType;

};
```

We need to change the connections for `int` type:

```
QObject::connect(topLevel, SIGNAL(submitTextField(int)),
                         &handleTextField, SLOT(handleSubmitTextField(int)));
```

and finally the signal is declared as:

```
signal submitTextField(int text)
```